# Issue with getting the Boxever Id for Anonymous user in CDP

Tags: cdp

I'm getting the following error while trying to get the Boxever Id for anonymous
VM121:1 **Uncaught ReferenceError: Boxevr is not defined
at :1:1**

Attached the script screen shot[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks good but seems one property is missing here i.e. POS
https://files.slack.com/files-pri/T09SHRBNU-F05CB52TAJG/image.png

```
var _boxeverq = _boxeverq || [];
    // Define the Boxever settings
    var _boxever_settings = {
        client_key: 'your key', //Replace with your client key display in screen shot
        target: 'https://api.boxever.com/v1.2',// Replace with your API target endpoint specific to your data center region
        cookie_domain: 'dev.sitecorecdp.demo', //Replace with the top level cookie domain of the website that is being integrated
        pointOfSale: "your POS", //Replace with newly created POS
        web_flow_target: 'https://d35vb5cccm4xzp.cloudfront.net'
    };
    // Import the Boxever library asynchronously
    (function () {
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.type = 'text/javascript';
        s.async = true;
        s.src = 'https://d1mj578wat5n4o.cloudfront.net/boxever-1.4.8.min.js';
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
    })();
```

I HAVE TRIED IT AND IT IS WORKING FINE ON MY SYTEM.

Please try it out, and as you are in learning phase you can start with Engage SDK, for better future support.